# Returning multiple lowest value rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a select query which returns a list of data and I need to return all rows with the lowest common level.

```
SELECT code, level
FROM table
ORDER BY level
```

For Example

```
code | level
-----+------
A01  |  3
B56  |  3
J33  |  4
J35  |  4
K56  |  4
```

I would like to return all results with the lowest level value so in this case it would be

```
A01  |  3
B56  |  3
```

I have tried using `MIN(level)` but this only returns the top row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES code, level
FROM table
ORDER BY level
```

Comment: @Andomar - No it's been there since [at least 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Very easy solution especially when the queries get more complex!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  level IN (SELECT Min(level) 
                 FROM   mytable)
order by level
```